# jQuery switching the value of Data Attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

I am having some trouble with updating the value of data attribute.
I have a large image and below it few thumbnails. What I wanted to do is when any of the thumbnail is clicked then it would update the image source and data attribute value for the big image. So far I am able to change the source but not the data attribute. I did see some similar questions and tried there solutions but so far non worked for me.

Here is my code:

**HTML** (I am using dummy image source just to explain my code)

```
<div class="bigImage">
  <img id="zoom_Photo" src="NormalSize.jpg" data-zoom-image="BigSize.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="additional-Photos">
    <img src="thumb1.jpg" data-pop="NormalSizeThumb1.jpg" />
    <img src="thumb2.jpg" data-pop="NormalSizeThumb2.jpg" />
    <img src="thumb3.jpg" data-pop="NormalSizeThumb3.jpg" />
</div>
         // This Script Triggers the Zoom Effect on Big Image
         <script>
            $('#zoom_Photo').elevateZoom({
              zoomType: "inner",
              cursor: "crosshair",
              zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
              zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
           }); 
        </script>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#additional-Photos .product-thumb').click(function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).data('pop');
    $('#zoom_Photo').attr('src',imgSrc);
    $('#zoom_Photo').data('zoom-image',imgSrc);
});
```

The image source for image ID **#zoom_Photo** is changing when clicked but its data attribute **data-zoom-image** is not updating.

I am using a jQuery plugin to zoom the images and the data-zoom-image attibute is required by it. The plugin is [Elevate Zoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom).

Comment: Missing `=` after `data-pop` in this example

Comment: yes @René its my typing mistake. sorry about it

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Your *«I forgot to mention»* leads to something else...
What said earlier is still true.

But since there is a plugin instantiated on that element, whatever you change to it won't reflect in the plugin instance.

Now... The plugin is creating new elements. It is not you original `<img>` that is showing.

Look for the ["gallery"](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#gallery-lightbox) feature... And come back with a new question if there is an issue.

---

**Previous answer**

Both are uptating...

But for the second one, the data **value**, it isn't reflecting in the view-source. That's all.

If your try a `console.log($('#zoom_Photo').data('zoom-image'));` after the update, you will have the right value. To have it reflecting in the view-source, you would have to update the attribute itself...

Comment: Same way as you did for the `src` attribute. But what is important here... is the value. The attribute is just to provide it on load via the HTML markup.

Comment: Updating just the attribute may not update the value... Since for the DOM, the object has already been parsed.

Comment: already tried this `$('#zoom_Photo').attr('zoom-image', imgSrc)` to update the data attribute but didnt work.

Comment: That would be: `$('#zoom_Photo').attr('data-zoom-image', imgSrc)`... But care about my previous comment ;)

Comment: yes this as well `$('#zoom_Photo').attr('data-zoom-image', imgSrc)` but the source code is still showing the previous value. data-zoom-image value triggers the zoom effect for that image. that has to be updated as well

Comment: Sure, you can update both the attribute and the value (which aren't tied after markup parsing)... But like said, for your JS, only the value is important. Who reads the view-source anyway, except you while debugging? .oO(lol)

Comment: friend that is the problem, the jQuery plugin to zoom the image is still showing the previous value, according to my sample code its displaying `data-zoom-image="BigSize.jpg"` .. maybe if value is updated in source code then it will zoom the new image

Comment: Ho! I just got it... You have a plugin instantiated on the element... That is something else. Let me re-read your question. I haven't seen it.

Comment: There no mention of the plugin used. Edit your question please... And add the script where it is instantiated.

Comment: i added the plugin detail

Answer (score 1):

> I am having some trouble with updating the value of data attribute.

Per the jQuery documentation for [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

Thus the attribute in the DOM ***never*** changes using this method.  If you need to *change* the attribute, use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

> yes this as well $('#zoom_Photo').attr('data-zoom-image', imgSrc) but the source code is still showing the previous value. data-zoom-image value triggers the zoom effect for that image. that has to be updated as well

Yes because the source code *never* changes, it's the source of the document, not the current value.

Comment: so how will i tell the plugin Elevate Zoom to use the new value?

Comment: It won't.  The programmers do not have this functionality.  The only solution I see is to remove the entire set of related html elements, re-add them  updated and run the plug-in again.